# How can I throttle the CPU to 80% and load balance my C++ function across 4 vCores on Debian 10?

Tags: c++, linux, load-balancing, cpu, cpu-usage

I wrote a processor intensive computing function that pegs the CPU at 100% on one vCore. It's a VM Server I am renting.

We have 8 vCores, but I'd like to throttle CPU usage to 80% and load balance across 4 vCores. I usually have the function allocate between 5 - 10 GB of RAM for computation.

The OS is Debian 10, and my specs are 24 GB of RAM, 8 vCores, and 250GB SSD.

The language is C++. I don't know if it's better to do this in code, or at the OS level. And how would I best do this?

Comment: Throttling aside, Assuming that your "function" is single threaded, your least headache-inducing option for distributing the work across cores would most likely be to make use of [openmp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP)

Comment: As far as throttling goes, that's precisely what [cpulimit](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/cpulimit/cpulimit.1.en.html) is for. However, if your code takes 100% of the cpu, then it means the machine has nothing better to do, so why bother throttling in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to throttle CPU usage to 80%

That 80% is an average of CPU usage over total wall clock, it's an estimate. A physical CPU core has exactly two states: doing something or not doing something.

So you at the very least need to figure out a requirement that makes sense here. For example, every 100 processed items, you sleep for 20% of the time that processing took (thus giving you 80% on average).

Of course this is most likely a stupid requirement born out of misunderstanding of the actual problem you're trying to solve (maybe you failed at load balancing your thread pool threads and they took over the main thread's processing time?), but go ahead and pepper your code with sleeps if that's your coding pattern. The guy they'll hire after they fire you will just remove the sleeps and make the software run 20% faster.

> load balance across 4 vCores

More buzzwords without understanding the problem space at hand. This is bad, because multi-threading and synchronization is extremely difficult, and if you haven't even a clue about what you're doing you might as well leave your code single threaded. You personally will break your code trying to do this otherwise.

Load balancing by the way is nothing more than making your code multi-threaded, and using the threads in a balanced way (as in, use the cores equally), and that's a very difficult problem of designing your algorithm from the get go to be partitionable, and run each partition on a different core. If you didn't do this, you'll rewrite it all from scratch anyway.